# PHP - Radio Button with array

Tags: php, html, arrays

[image]

The default value is the first radio button. 
The output like this: 1=>Y  ,2=>N ,3=>N 
OK, no problem.

Now my question is, I want to click the third radio button.
The expected output like this: 1=>N, 2=>N, 3=>Y
But my output like this: 1=>N, 2=>Y, 3=>Y
The second one should be N, not Y.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $defaultkey = array("Y","N","N");

    for($i = 1; $i <= count($defaultkey); $i++)
    {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php echo $defaultkey[$i-1]; ?>"><?php echo $defaultkey[$i-1];?><br />      
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if($_POST['choice']=="Y")
   {
       for($j = 1; $j <=count($defaultkey); $j++)
       {
           echo ($j). '=>' .$defaultkey[$j-1]. '<br />';
       }
   }
   else if($_POST['choice']=="N")
   {
       for($k = 1; $k <=count($defaultkey); $k++)
       {
           if($_POST['choice']==$defaultkey[$k-1])
           {
               $defaultkey[$k-1] = "Y";
               echo ($k). '=>' .$defaultkey[$k-1]. '<br />';
           }
           else
           {
               $defaultkey[$k-1] = "N";
               echo ($k). '=>' .$defaultkey[$k-1]. '<br />';
           }
       }
   }
}
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: what happends when you select the middle `N`, what should be the order then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know how web forms data work. Your current radio buttons are:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="Y">Y
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="N">N
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="N">N
```

So you **can't** find out which radio button is select  (1, 2, or 3). Try to change the value of them:

```
<?php
    $defaultkey = array("Y","N","N");

    for($i = 1; $i <= count($defaultkey); $i++)
    {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $defaultkey[$i-1];?><br />    

    <?php
    }
?>
```

Which generate this:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">Y
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">N
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">N
```

And in your Submit:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($defaultkey); $i++) {
            echo $i . ' => ' . ($_POST['choice'] == $i ? 'Y' : 'N') . '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
for($k = 1; $k <=count($defaultkey); $k++)
       {
           if($_POST['choice']==$defaultkey[$k-1])
           {
               $defaultkey[$k-1] = "Y";
               echo ($k). '=>' .$defaultkey[$k-1]. '<br />';
           }
           else
           {
               $defaultkey[$k-1] = "N";
               echo ($k). '=>' .$defaultkey[$k-1]. '<br />';
           }
       }
```

When you check the last radio button, your choice is N. Your 2nd item in defaultkey array is N also, so when you loop through, $_POST['choice'] == $defaultkey[ 1 ] will return true before it reach the $defaultkey[ 2 ].

You have to rewrite your php logic, I don't quite understand what do you want to achieve in your code, so I can't advise you how to re-write.

Comment: You can use method suggested by @ROX or use input array (http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

There's no fixed answer to this question, you have to know all the possible alternatives and pick one that suit your current situation more.